# Execute macro after creating word document from an external program

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an external program or more like database, where information like names, adress and other things of people is stored. Through that program I can create a template that automatically fills out the desired information in an word or excel document. The problem is that I would love to automatically use a macro in vba after a new document is created using this template, but `Document_New()`, `Document_Open()`, `Auto_Open()`, `Auto_New()` and `AutoExe()` did not work. The macro just will not fire after the new document is created, but I can manually use it after. If anyone got any ideas I would be really thankful.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
Sub Document_Open()

 'different functions

End sub
```

I also tried using the commands above in `normal.dot`, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Is the code in normal.dot?  Can you [edit the question to include it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54951562/edit)?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286310/description-of-behaviors-of-autoexec-and-autoopen-macros-in-word   Seems like `AutoOpen` should work.

Comment: Maybe you need an [event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word) on application level.

Comment: `AutoOpen()` doesn't work though, it feels like my external program is filling the place holder automatically after creating the new file and doesn't run any macros, and afterwards the document is already seen as "opened" or "created" so the macros won't run. Unfortunately I have no access to the code of my external program.

Comment: So just to be clear, it's creating a new document based on the template, and the handler is in the template it's based on?

Comment: This works just fine with `Document_New()` in a .dotm file and `Documents.Add "E:\Test\Doc1.dotm"` when it's called from Excel.  I feel like we're missing something here.

Comment: Maybe your application specifically suppresses macros when creating the document.

Comment: It's really weird, if I open a document created by the template after closing it before `Document_Open()` for example works fine, and all macros are working. But nothing happens directly after the document is created, except for the placeholders of the template that are now filled with data.

Comment: It does, indeed, seem that the program that runs from the database is "automating" the Word document. It is possible, in the Word VBA object model, to "turn off" execution of macros when automating Word. In that case, you either have to use your own code to create the documents based on the data or ask the software manufacturer of the tool the database is using whether something like what you envision could be incorporated into that program.

Comment: There are 2 events with different behaviors.  `Document_New()` fires when a document is created from the template. `Document_Open()` fires when the document based on the template is subsequently opened.  Are you saving the document as a .docm file?

Comment: yeah maybe the external programm supresses macros, which I don't hope tho. Yes I saved the template as a .docm file and the newly created document is also .docm

Comment: If the document is created by your other application then it likely doesn't meet the criteria for Auto macros or Document events.  Instead you might want to investigate the Application.Run method which can run a macro based on a string which is the name of the macro to run.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.run?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158335421)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396